# How to do a 'printline' in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, lua

I have just started exploring the world of LuaTeX and wanted to write a piece of code, that prints a name to a new line in the document.

```
\directlua{
for i=1,3,1 do
tex.print("FOO")
end
}
```

which should produce the following output:

```
FOO
FOO
FOO
```

rather than:

```
FOO FOO FOO
```

How do I use Lua correctly? I have tried messing with `\\` and many other things over the course of an hour. Am I approaching this problem from the wrong angle? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try `tex.print("Foo", "\par")`

Comment: @Marco Somehow I have the feeling that it is pure luck that this works. Lua does not see the `\par` but something else, which I don't know at the moment.

Comment: Khaled explains why in his answer. (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53075/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using LaTeX (LuaLaTeX), I'd strongly advice against using `\directlua{}` for more than a simple call to execute another Lua file. `\directlua{}` is in no way safe. For example:

- if you use a Lua comment (`--`), your code gets Q="!%"§I. This is because in `\directlua{}` everything is read on one line.
- If you try to use a literal `%` sign, for example in `tex.print()` you... well, try yourself . Good luck.
- If you try to use an active character such as `~` surprising results are guaranteed.
- When you want to use `tex.print()` with a macro, such as `\par`, you have do crazy stuff to not let TeX see the macro before Lua sees the macro.
- And good luck inserting strings like "\n" for a new line character.

Now what to do? Use the environment `luacode*` from the *luacode* package:

```
\begin{luacode*}
  for i=1,3,1 do
    tex.print("FOO\\par")
  end  
\end{luacode*}
```

If you can't use the *luacode* package (for example when you use plain TeX), use `dofile()` or `require()` to load a package and put your code there. TeX can't find and interpret the code there, only Lua. And then you can write

```
for i=1,3,1 do
  tex.print("FOO\\par")
end
```

without trouble.

Answer (score 9):

`tex.print` appends `\endlinechar` to each string it prints except the last, so just print an empty string at the end.

```
\directlua{
for i=1,3,1 do
tex.print("FOO", "")
end
}
\bye
```

Answer (score 6):

Two problems here: A `"\\"` in Lua just gets you one literal backslash which TeX stumbles over; as in the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50283/9092) you must use `"\\\\"` or `[[\\]]`. Also, `\directlua` expands control sequences within it; so if you want to pass a control sequence verbatim into Lua you'll need to either`\noexpand` it or use `\luaexec` instead.

Any of these three would work:

```
\directlua{
    for i=1,3,1 do
    tex.print([[FOO\noexpand\\]])
    end
}
```

---

```
\luaexec{
    for i=1,3,1 do
    tex.print([[FOO\\]])
    end
}
```

---

```
\luaexec{nl = [[\\]]}
\directlua{
    for i=1,3,1 do
    tex.print("FOO" .. nl)
    end
}
```

Comment: Any ways to be able to print `"\n\n"`? I tried that but I get an error? I know it works in lua itself but texlua seems different.