# How to raise a LaTeX warning from within Lua code?

Tags: errors, luatex, warnings, package-writing

I want to raise a warning from within Lua code. With advice from the [LuaTeX wiki](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Writing_Lua_in_TeX#Backslash) and [LaTeX 2 for class and package writers](http://texdoc.net/pkg/clsguide), I arrived at the following (working) solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Foo
\directlua{
myvar = "\noexpand\\PackageWarning{mypackage}{Hello, I am a warning.}"
tex.print(myvar)
}
\end{document}
```

This seems unnecessarily complex, considering that raising an error is as easy as:

```
\directlua{
tex.error("Hi, I'm an error!")
}
```

While I'm aware that `tex.error` is a generic TeX error and the warning I'm producing is a package-specific warning, I still think for both generic LaTeX warnings (if that exists?) and package-specific warnings (as well as package-specific errors, probably), there should be an easier way. Is there one?

Comment: @cyberSingularity: Indeed, I wasn't sure whether that was a TeX or LaTeX thing. I edited my question, please let me know if there are still any imprecise statements in it.

Comment: `tex.print("\noexpand\\PackageWarning{pack}{Text}")` seems easier.

Comment: @cyberSingularity Better yet, `tex.print([[\unexpanded{\PackageWarning{pack}{Text}}]])` so that macros in `Text` will be expanded only on the TeX side.

Comment: @doncherry The warning mechanism in LaTeX uses `\write` on an output string that is never open, so by rule the contents is written both to the terminal and in the log file.

Comment: @cyberSingularity My last comment was just to explain how LaTeX treats warnings. What about `tex.iowrite`? My knowledge of Lua is rather primitive, so I can't see if and how it could help.

Comment: @egreg: I have removed my comments in favour of an answer. Sorry for misinterpreting what you said about how LaTeX treats warnings, but I think it's still important not to try to emulate LaTeX commands in Lua, and I was worried that was a route that might be taken given your comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Someone who is more familiar with Lua will almost certainly have better ideas...

egreg's idea from the comments makes things slightly easier: consider using the `[[...]]` string syntax so you don't need to escape the string (but there will still be issues if the string itself contains a `]]` etc), and use eTeX's `\unexpanded` so you don't need to worry so much about putting `\noexpand` everywhere. See also some of the [suggestions about `\directlua` on a different question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53087/17427).

As I previously mentioned in a comment, bypassing/emulating the LaTeX commands for this is probably not a good idea. LaTeX's commands for this are slightly more complicated than you might first think, and might get patched/hooked into. Even rewriting LaTeX in Lua (replacing eg `\PackageWarning` with something that invokes a Lua script/function) wouldn't necessarily help in the latter situation.

I think the best you could do would be to write your own Lua function that invokes LaTeX's `\PackageWarning`, taking care to escape parameters etc as appropriate. (Sorry, I'm not proficient enough to attempt that.)

Compare the terminal output from the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\PackageWarningNoLine{mypackage}{Hello, I am a warning}
\PackageWarning{mypackage}{Hello, I am a warning}
\directlua{
texio.write_nl("term and log", [[\unexpanded{Package mypackage Warning: Hello, I am a warning.}]]);
tex.print([[\unexpanded{\PackageWarning{mypackage}{Hello, I am a warning}}]]);
}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I have used `"term and log"` here because (as egreg explained), LaTeX normally writes to an `\@unused` stream that is never open, so the output appears both on the terminal and in the log file.

The output is

```
Package mypackage Warning: Hello, I am a warning.


Package mypackage Warning: Hello, I am a warning on input line 3.

Package mypackage Warning: Hello, I am a warning.

Package mypackage Warning: Hello, I am a warning on input line 1.
```

Note also that the line numbers from the Lua version are wrong, even when the real `\PackageWarning` command is invoked.

For reference, some relevant definitions from `latex.ltx`:

```
\def\set@display@protect{\let\protect\string}
\def\@spaces{\space\space\space\space}
\ifnum\inputlineno=\m@ne
  \let\on@line\@empty
\else
  \def\on@line{ on input line \the\inputlineno}
\fi
\DeclareRobustCommand{\GenericWarning}[2]{%
   \begingroup
      \def\MessageBreak{^^J#1}%
      \set@display@protect
      \immediate\write\@unused{^^J#2\on@line.^^J}%
   \endgroup
}
\def\PackageWarning#1#2{%
   \GenericWarning{%
      (#1)\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces\@spaces
   }{%
      Package #1 Warning: #2%
   }%
}
\def\PackageWarningNoLine#1#2{%
   \PackageWarning{#1}{#2\@gobble}%
}
```

Comment: From what I see, `texio.write` is quite similar to TeX's `\message`

Comment: @egreg: Agreed, though the LuaTeX reference manual doesn't make that comparison so they may behave differently in some ways...

Comment: With `term and log` it is the same as `\message`; with `log` it's the same as `\wlog`; it has no counterpart with `term`.