# Where to find a list of all available symbols for ConTeXt?

Tags: symbols, context

As mentioned in [Which symbols need to be escaped in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48933/which-symbols-need-to-be-escaped-in-context), one can type commands, such as `\textdollar` to display symbols in a document. In some situations, using such commands seems advantageous, for instance, in allowing one to distinguishing content from code and for allowing one to make consistent, document-wide changes to symbols which should appear as text, but not to those symbols being used in ConTeXt and Lua code. Where can I find a comprehensive list of text commands which display symbols in Unicode using the currently selected font?

- [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol) provides instructions for finding symbols, but the solutions, such as [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) do not seem relevant to ConTeXt.
- The ConTeXt wiki has an article about [symbols](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Symbols), however, this does not contain many of the items mentioned in [Which symbols need to be escaped in ConTeXt?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48933/which-symbols-need-to-be-escaped-in-contex), which suggests to me that more special commands might be available.
- [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) contains a list of symbols, some of which function in ConTeXt, but the document does not single out which symbol commands have been implemented in ConTeXt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definitive guide is [char-def.lua](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/char-def.lua) file in the distribution. It contains a table of all(?) unicode symbols and the ConTeXt macro for them (grep for `contextname`). It also contains the math macro name and the math class for symbols, where relevant.

Just find the unicode slot for the symbol you are looking for and search for it in `char-def.lua`. If you find a symbol name is missing (the table is not complete yet), write to the mailing list and it will be added in the list.

Comment: What happens if the symbols is listed, but there is no line for `contextname`? Are there alternative ways to type the character, such as typing `0x005D`?

Comment: In that case, there is no ConTeXt macro for them. For a few symbols, additional `\letter....` mappings are defined in `catc-sys.mkiv`. For Lua, few additional `lualetter...` mappings are defined in `luat-ini.mkiv`. In the worst case, you can always define your own mappings: `\xdef\letterlbrace{[}`, etc.

Comment: If you think that there should be a macro corresponding to a certain symbol because that macro exists in LaTeX/AMS/etc, write to the context mailing list.

Comment: Assuming that you use an unicode encoded open type font you should be able to insert a char with ` ^^^^005d `

Comment: If I define my own mappings, e.g. with `\xdef\letterlbrace{[}` will the same spacing rules which are given to that symbol be applied?

Comment: @Village: I believe so.